# Searching an Array, and printing it out

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have a 2d array. In there is a character `U`. My code searches for the character and then outputs the array, but only showing the `U` and every character around it. Somewhere my code goes wrong and the `U` seems to be output just opposite of where it should be.

The original array is `gameboard[]`, it is read in fine. Also we can't use vectors, pointers, just what i have already used

```
int boardSizeRow;
    int boardSizeCol;
    inputFile.open("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\fileboard1.txt");
    inputFile >> boardSizeRow;
    inputFile >> boardSizeCol;
    inputFile.get();
    char gameBoard[21][21];
    for (int row = 0; row <= boardSizeRow; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= boardSizeCol; col++)
        {
            gameBoard[row][col] = inputFile.get();
        }
        //inputFile.get();
    }
    for (int row = 0; row <= boardSizeRow; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= boardSizeCol; col++)
        {
            cout << gameBoard[row][col];
        }
        //cout << endl;
    }
bool toPrint[21][21] = {false}; 
for (int i = 0; i < boardSizeRow; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSizeCol; j++)
    {
        if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'U')
       {
           toPrint[i][j] = true; 
           toPrint[i][j-1] = true; //West
           toPrint[i][j+1] = true; //East
           toPrint[i-1][j] = true;  //North
           toPrint[i+1][j] = true; //South  

       }
   }
}
for (int i = 0; i < boardSizeRow; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSizeCol; j++)
    {
       if (toPrint[i][j] == true)
       {            
           cout << gameBoard[i][j];
       }
       else
       {
           cout << "0";
       }
    }
    cout<<endl;
 }
```

original array:

```
WWWWWWWWWW
W WW GO  W
W WW WWW W
W   W   GW
WPWG  WW W
WWWDWK  WW
W  GW W  W
W WW  KWAW
W   SW  UW
WWWWWWWWWW
```

** Wanted output:

```
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
00000000A0
00000000UW
00000000W0
```

here is a example of a random output i get: http://tinypic.com/r/2ujo8/6

Comment: The print order should be: North, West, U, East, South. Is this what you expect?

Comment: Are you sure where you think it should be is where it really is? Construct a complete, runnable example that shows the behaviour that you think is incorrect.

Comment: What if gameBoard[0][0] = 'U', then negative indexes will be used for toPrint array.

Comment: Is this safe?? `toPrint[i][j+1] = true; //East` I mean when `j= boardSizeCol` you will be accessing outside the array. I think that should give you errors

Comment: @Dukeling When i printed out the read-in array it was displayed fine, but when i display the same array but only showing the U and everything around it it isnt where it is supposed to be.

Comment: @Haroogan I wasnt sure the print order mattered, i want it all to be displayed exactly how it looks in the original array

Comment: Show the code that prints the read-in array.

Comment: Completely off-topic but "if (toPrint[i][j] == true)" is a bit repetitive...

Comment: @user2274252: What do you mean the way how it looks in the array? You want the output to be formatted as a "crest" with `U` character in the center? Currently, your code should print it sequentially - the way I've posted in the first comment. Elaborate what is the exact problem and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry its a 2d array. 10x10. When i display the U i want to be in the exact spot as it is in the original 2d array.

Comment: You can replace that if-else-statement with: `cout << (toPrint[i][j] ? gameBoard[i][j] : "0");`

Comment: @Haroogan look at my edits maybe youll get a better idea

Comment: Don't see any problem either. Can you write some comments and not just post an output?

Comment: @Dukeling  sorry that is my "Wanted" output

Comment: @user2274252: Here we go again, and where is the wrong output then?

Comment: the output just displays everything in one line, unless i break off the line like i did in the code, but that still leaves the U positioned opposite of where it needs to be

Comment: @user2274252: Oh, man, _"opposite"_ is too vague in this context. Could you finally post the example, where it is _"opposite"_ from what is desired?

Comment: @Haroogan http://tinypic.com/r/2ujo8/6    here is a pic of the output, it seems to be opposite

Comment: @user2274252: In your question the size of `toPrint` is `21` by `21` and on the screenshot it is `20` by `20`.

Comment: @Haroogan its because when reading the original file, i couldnt get the array to display right, the .txt file's first two lines are the deminsion of the array, so for example it the first two lines wouldve been 20 and 20, then the array would follow. When reading in it would not display the full board unless i expanded the array to 21x21

Comment: @Haroogan http://tinypic.com/r/2zxnofs/6  this is the error i get when defing the array as 20x20 with code: char gameBoard[20][20]; Even when i change the toPrint array to 20x20, and keep gameBoard at 21x21, i still get the same bad output

Comment: @user2274252: Yes because you continue to use `boardSizeRow` and `boardSizeCol` to traverse the array and therefore fall out of bounds. Use consistent dimensions for both. Perhaps use both `boardSizeRow` and `boardSizeCol` as the dimensions for both arrays. And use them to create `toPrint` as hard-coding `21` by `21` dimensions is just wrong since you can read them from the file. Do `bool* toPrint = new bool[boardSizeRow][boardSizeCol]();`.

Comment: @Haroogan the thing is we cant use pointers, and i only get that error when declaring the first array (gameboard) as 21 by 21, 20x20 is the largest possible size the file can be, its possible it could be 10x10, but if its 20x20 then i can only get it to display properly by creating the first array as char gameBoard[21][21]

Comment: @user2274252: Time to edit your post and show how you actually create `gameBoard`, populate it, and print it. I can already see that you have troubles fully understanding how arrays work.

Comment: @Haroogan ok i added in how i got the original array

Comment: It should be `row < boardSizeRow`, not `row <= boardSizeRow`, and same for `col`. Then you can set both `char gameBoard[20][20];` and `bool toPrint[20][20] = {false};` to be `20` by `20` safely.

Comment: @Haroogan http://tinypic.com/r/2v84t20/6 heres the result. That almost gets it! but its not reading in the original array, i think it has something to do with the fact that the first two lines in the file are 20 and 20. Also the second array doesnt display the characters around the U properly

Comment: I suspect that you have newlines after each row of characters in the file, therefore you have to uncomment `inputFile.get();` to skip them.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/qphrpv/6   i did that there still a little issue, and when i uncommented the endl it just made things even worse and more wack

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < boardSizeRow; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSizeCol; j++)
    {
        if (gameBoard[i][j] == 'U')
       {

           toPrint[i][j] = true; 
           if(j!=0)
            toPrint[i][j-1] = true; //West
           if(j!=(boardSizeCol-1))
            toPrint[i][j+1] = true; //East
           if(i!=0)
           toPrint[i-1][j] = true;  //North
           if(i!=(boardSizeRow -1))
           toPrint[i+1][j] = true; //South  

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is still not safe. You need to check `j < (boardSizeCol-1)` and `i < (boardSizeRow-1)`

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. It's equivalent given the for-loop exit condition.

Answer (score -1):

Thought about switching rows and columns for printing?

```
for (int j = 0; j < boardSizeCol; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSizeRow; i++ )
    {
       if (toPrint[i][j] == true)
       {            
           cout << gameBoard[i][j];
       }
       else
       {
           cout << "0";
       }
    }
    cout<<endl;
 }
```